# Using C#, how do I "Include" a file into a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, envdte

Thanks for looking.

I have a small program that generates a new .NET solution based on some project information and a database connection.

As part of this process, I automatically generate the ADO.NET entity data model/`.edmx` file using [edmgen2](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2).

This code works fine and generates the .edmx, etc which is added to the project's folder in Windows.

## The Problem

When I open the generated solution and subsequently the DAL project which contains the `.edmx`, I must then show excluded files, right-click, and then `include` the .edmx manually.

This isn't a huge deal, but it would be nicer if I could call come code after the `.edmx` is generated that would automatically include it in the VS Project.

Is this possible?

## ADDING TO THE ANSWERS BELOW:

The answers below got me going but I did find that I couldn't operate on the .csproj xml in the usual ways that I alter other xml files.  You have to use the `msbuild` namespace.  Here is what worked for me:

```
var csproj = XDocument.Load(SolutionFolder + @"\SomeProject.csproj");
XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
var itemGroups = csproj.Descendants(msbuild + "ItemGroup");
var itemGroup = itemGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Descendants(msbuild + "Compile").Any());
var item = new XElement(msbuild + "Compile");
item.SetAttributeValue("Include", "ApplicationEntityModel.edmx");
itemGroup.Add(item);
csproj.Save(SolutionFolder + @"\SomeProject.csproj");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested:
You can edit your *.csproj file and add your new file to  `<ItemGroup>` section. It is an xml file that can be edited programitically.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="fileName" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

The C# project file `*.csproj` is actually a XML file, so after your tool finishes generating the solution, you can open the desired project file as XML ([`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), etc.) and add to it [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164283.aspx) element which will point to the generated `.edmx` file.